# How to browse the iTunes Store without iTunes?

Tags: itunes

Sometimes I just want to see an App description, and when I click on it, my browser goes to a page from Apple which immediately starts to screw up my machine. Reason: Heavy iTunes launches and eats up 95% of my system resources. Beach ball for minutes!

And now I want to browse podcasts and it makes me so angry that I can't just have a normal browser. For example, inside iTunes I can't open things in a new window so that I don't get lost from where I came from. It's so limited and memory consuming.

Maybe there's a way how to browse the iTunes store contents with a normal web browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[App Store](http://app-store.appspot.com/) is a Google App Engine app which browses the iTunes Store.  It's not very pretty, but gets the job done.

Update: If you're using Safari, you'll probably be interested in the [NoMoreiTunes](http://einserver.de/nomoreitunes/) extension that makes iTunes Store links not open the browser.